# mysql command line can no longer see any databases

Tags: mysql

I am running a local mysql server to work with some old data from a dump. I am able to normally log into the database using:

```
/mysql -uroot -p
```

and in fact the `show databases` command correctly outputs the following, I am also able to execute queries and use the data normally:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| servicenow2        |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

now the problem is I was using command line to import some files from my old dump:

```
/mysql -uroot -p servicenow2</filetoimport.sql
```

however this command no longer works always resulting in (for all dbs in the server):

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'servicenow2'
```

I assume some schema got corrupted somewhere is there any way to fix this so I do not have to dump the db and reimport it the db I am working with is over 150gb and would take a very long time to dump and reimport.

update: I performed a flush privileges as described here : https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

now the command : `mysql -uroot -p servicenow2` correctly starts a client in the servicenow2 db but the import `mysql -uroot -p servicenow2</filetoimport.sql` still gives unknown db error.

Comment: Simple answer would be to uninstall and then reinstall your local instance of MySQL Server. That woudl rebuild the corrupted `mysql` database

Comment: yes i am trying to avoid that the `servicenow2` db is some 150gb in size I would rather fix it then potentially have to dump it and reimport

Answer (score 0):

Work around in case anyone is interested:

create a new db and import into the new db then move from table in new db to desired db